# Find the maximum of the function F under the condition $ \sum_{i=1}^N x_i = 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

Let F be a function of $ \mathbb{R} ^N_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  defined as :

$$F(x_1,..,x_N)= - \sum_{i=1}^N x_i log(x_i) , x_i \gt 0$$

How can I find the maximum of the function F under the condition $ \sum_{i=1}^N x_i = 1$?

I got really stuck on this problem I tried to derivate the function but can I get a solution to this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you should be able to show the $N = 2$ case that $x_1 = x_2 = \frac 12$ yields the maximum; then try to extend this argument for $N > 2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another proof, without using Lagrange (but probably less natural):

Consider two families $x=(x_1,\dots,x_N)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_N)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i=\sum_{i=1}^Ny_i=1$.

Then, we claim that $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\ln(y_i)\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\ln(x_i)$ (*) with equality if and only if $x_i=y_i$ for any $i=1,\dots,N$.

For, we have $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\ln(y_i)-\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\ln(x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\ln(\frac{y_i}{x_i})$ but, by a study of the function $\ln(x)-x+1$, we know that $\ln(x)\leqslant x-1$ for any $x>0$, and the equality occurs if and only if $x=1$.

So $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\ln(y_i)-\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\ln(x_i)\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^nx_i(\frac{y_i}{x_i}-1)=\sum_{i=1}^Ny_i-\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i=0$

Thus, applying the inequality (*) to $y_1=\dots=y_N=\frac{1}{N}$, we obtain that the minimum value of $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\ln(x_i)$ is $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\ln(\frac{1}{N})=-\ln(N)$, obtained when $x_i=y_i=\frac{1}{N}$ for any $i=1,\dots,N$.

By multiplication by $-1$, we obtain the desired result.

Comment: The previous answer, using Lagrange multipliers, has been deleted. Though it was not complete, it was very useful I think. It was not the intention of my comment to that answer to have it deleted.

Comment: Hi, why can you just multiply by $-1$ at the end?

Comment: I am also wondering whether this inequality holds for any log base, does it still hold for base $2$ as it does for base $e$ for example?

Comment: also you have found the minimum not the maximum - unless the multiplication by -1makes it the maximum somehow...?

Comment: @user71207: I can multiply by $-1$ at the end because nothing forbids to multiply by $-1$ (maybe I misunderstood your question). Note that $f$ has a maximum (resp. minimum) at $a$ if and only $-f$ has a minimum (resp. maximum) at $a$. I think the maximum of $F$ is obtained when $x_i=1/n$  in every base larger than $1$ since all log are multiples of each other. The inequality $\ln(x)\ge x-1$ in my proof needs to be adapted to the relevant base though.

Comment: Thank you, "Note that  has a maximum (resp. minimum) at  if and only − has a minimum (resp. maximum) at ." this clarified it for me and was the reason why I asked why you multiplied by -1. But now, why does equality of $y_k =...=1/n$ give a maximum/minimum?

Comment: @user71207: consider the function $G(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\ln(y_i)$ (so $F(x)=G(x,x)$). The inequality $(\ast)$ shows that $F(x)\ge G(x,y)$ for every $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ with $x_1>0,\dots,y_n>0$. Then, using $N=(\frac{1}{n},\dots,\frac{1}{n})$, we  have $F(x)\ge G(x,N)=-\ln(n)=F(N)$ for every $x$. This means that $F(N)$ is the minimum value of $F$.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying. So basically at equality, there is a maximum or minimum?

Comment: @user71207: I am not sure what you mean. By definition, $F$ has an absolute minimum at $a$ if $F(x)\ge F(a)$ for every $x$ in the domain of $F$.